# Authentication Creditial were not provided error in Django

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm pretty new in django, especially django rest framework. so i tried to follow some instruction in the internet. but when I test it using Postman, it gives an error that says

```
 "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
```

in the json file.

so what did I do wrong to be exact?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the `Authorization` token inside the header of a request, not the body,

so to fix that, go to **Headers** tab in **Postman**, add **Authorization** to the headers along with its value.

And it should be working.

Comment: not working, is there a problem with it? https://prnt.sc/vk3z78

Comment: Add TOKEN before your token value

Answer (score 0):

Authorization gets placed in headers instead of the body and the value should also include Token before your actual token inside of the value.

Key: `Authorization`

Value: `Token YOURTOKENHERE`

Comment: doesnt seems to be working either https://prnt.sc/vk6jvf

Comment: In your headers, not params